# R - parallelisation error, checkCluster(cl) - not a valid cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing

This code brings me an error: `Error in checkCluster(cl): not a valid cluster`

```
library(parallel)
numWorkers <-8

cl <-makeCluster(numWorkers, type="PSOCK")

   res.mat <- parLapply(1:10, function(x) my.fun(x))

stopCluster(cl)
```

Without parallelisation attempts this works totally fine:

```
res.mat <- lapply(1:10, function(x) my.fun(x))
```

And this example works very well too:

```
workerFunc <- function(n){return(n^2)}

library(parallel)

numWorkers <-8

cl <-makeCluster(numWorkers, type ="PSOCK")

res <- parLapply(cl, 1:100, workerFunc)

stopCluster(cl)

print(unlist(res))
```

How can i solve my problem?

I found for example

```
class(cl)
[1] "SOCKcluster" "cluster"
```

an cl is:

```
cl
socket cluster with 8 nodes on host ‘localhost’
```

Comment: The first argument to `parLapply` should be your cluster object.

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(parallel)
numWorkers <- 8

cl <-makeCluster(numWorkers, type="PSOCK")

res.mat <- parLapply(cl,1:10, function(x) my.fun(x))

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Please don't just post code. Give some insights to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be excessively specific, the problem with
`res.mat <- parLapply(1:10, function(x) my.fun(x))`
is not necessarily the order of the arguments, but that the argument `cl` is not specified.

```
cl <-makeCluster(numWorkers, type ="PSOCK")
res.mat <- parLapply(x = 1:10,
                     fun = function(x) my.fun(x),
                     cl = cl
                     )
```

should work, because all required arguments are specified. Alternatively, `?parLapply` indicates that `parLapply` uses the default cluster if `cl` is not specified. A default cluster can be set using `parallel::setDefaultCluster()`, which then allows `parLapply` to revert to default behaviour when `cl` is not included in the user input.

```
cl <-makeCluster(numWorkers, type ="PSOCK")
parallel::setDefaultCluster(cl)
res.mat <- parallel::parLapply(x = 1:10,#by default cl = NULL if not specified
                               fun = function(x) my.fun(x),
                               )
```